# cannot find symbol ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, symbols

Trying to compile this but can't figure out what's wrong. Have been struggeling with this for days now. Yes, I'm a newbie... Anybody could help me?
Getting the errors in the methods in the bottom of the code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankLogic
{
    private long pNr;
    private int accountId;
    private double amount;
    private double balance;
    private double rate;

    private ArrayList<Customer> customerlist;
    private ArrayList<SavingsAccount> accounts;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public BankLogic(){

        customerlist = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        accounts = new ArrayList<SavingsAccount>();
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public String toString(){

        String info = "Personnummer: " + pNr + "\nKontonummer: " + accountId
        + "\nSaldo: " + amount;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Beskrivning: returnerar presentation av alla kunder(pers.nr och namn)
    // Returvärde: String 
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public String infoBank(){

        return customerlist.toString();
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public boolean addCustomer(String name, long pNr){

        for (Customer a : customerlist)
        {
            if (a.getPCode() == pNr)
                return false;
            else
            {
                Customer aCust = new Customer(name, pNr);   
                customerlist.add(aCust);
            }
        }
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public String infoCustomer(long pNr){

        for (Customer a : customerlist)
        {
            if (a.getPCode() == pNr)
            {
                System.out.println(a);
            }
        }
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public boolean changeCustomerName(String name, long pNr){

        for (Customer a : customerlist)
        {
            if (a.getPCode() == pNr)
            {
                Customer aCust = new Customer(name, pNr);   
                customerlist.add(aCust);
            }
        else
            return false;
        }
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public String removeCustomer(long pNr){

        for (int i = 0; i < customerlist.length; i++)
        {
            Customer a = customerlist.get(i);
            if (a.getPCode() == pNr)
            {
                customerlist.remove(i);
            }
            else
                i++;
        }

    }


    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public int addSavingsAccount(long pNr){

        for (Customer a : customerlist)
        {
            if (a.getPCode() == pNr)
            {
                boolean added = false;
                for (int i = 0; !added && i < accounts.size(); i++)
                {
                    added = accounts.get(i).addAccount(a);
                    if(added)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Kontonummer: " + accounts.get(i).getAccountId();
                    }
                    else 
                        return "Kontot skapades inte.";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public String infoAccount(long pNr, int accountId)
    {
        for (Customer a : customerlist)
        {
           if (a.getAccountId() == accountId && a.getPCode() == pNr)
               return a.infoCust();
         } 
       return null; 
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public boolean deposit(long pNr, int accountId, double amount){

        for (Customer a : customerlist)
        {
           if ((a.SavingsAccount.getAccountId() == accountId) && (a.getPCode() == pNr))
            {
                a.SavingsAccount.getBalance() = balance + amount;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public boolean withdraw(long pNr, int accountId, double amount){

        for (Customer a : customerlist)
        {
           if ((a.getAccountId() == accountId) && (a.getPCode() == pNr))
            {
                a.getBalance() = balance - amount;
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please include the exact errors and the lines that are causing them.

Comment: ? Are you using an IDE like eclipse or smthg ? How do you compile ? javac ?

Comment: Compiling this online gives an error at line 118: https://ideone.com/eNqqga. You need an extra ")".

Comment: I haven't been to java for a while, but I don't think this makes sense: a.getBalance() = balance - amount;

Comment: @Mia You have a few problems in your code. For one thing, all of your methods declare that they will return something. Most of your methods however don't guarantee a return value through all of the different paths through the code. I think your best bet would be to start again from this class, adding in methods one at a time and checking that they compile as you go.

Comment: I'm compiling with javac and using Dreamweaver to write the code. @avik - is it so bad? :-/ I get the cannot find symbol errors from line 116 and down, "customerlist.length", ".addAccount(a)", "a.getAccountId()", "a.infoCust()", "(a.SavingsAccount.", "a.getBalance()".

Comment: oh my god... get an eclipse or netbeans and use it to write the code, it will change your life ;)

Comment: I downloaded eclipse and I se what you mean, Gab. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below two statements are incorrect. Left hand side of an expression must be a variable and in your case it is a value.

```
        a.SavingsAccount.getBalance() = balance + amount;


          a.getBalance() = balance - amount;
```

correct them by using appropriate variables or setter methods. Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually SavingsAccount is very wrong here I can se by now. Going thru the methods one by one and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

There's all sorts of errors in the above code I can see at a glance:

- `toString()` isn't returning anything (it just declares a local variable that's then immediately garbage collected as the method ends)
- `addCustomer()` doesn't always return something.
- `infoCustomer()` and `removeCustomer()` never return anything, despite declaring that they should in the method header
- `addSavingsAccount()` should return an int (according to the method header), but only returns a string - sometimes.
- Unless `Customer` has a public field called `SavingsAccount` (which would be hideously bad design from so many respects) then `a.SavingsAccount.getAccountId()` and similar is wrong, you probably want the method on `Customer` that gets its particular savings account.

You need to get into the habit of checking your code in much smaller increments, at least until you have a handle on the basic syntactical side of things. That way you won't end up in these sorts of scenarios where there's a ton of errors that you have to fix, with no real knowledge of how to fix them.

Every time you add (for instance) a method: stop, compile, check it works as you want it to, and only then move onto the next thing. It'll save you a heck of a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to get them thru one by one now.